# Multiple If Statements using variable

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I am trying to make some logic controls on input variables `$ContentPicture1Title` and `$ContentPicture1URL`. In particular I am trying to get **two rules applied** in a single `if` statement.

In the first piece of code was everything ok. Then I messed out the code as you can see in the second snippet.

First statement (OK):

```
<?php if (is_null($ContentPicture1Title)){ ?>
   <div class="letter-badge"><img src="image1.jpg"></div>
<?php } else { ?>
   <div class="letter-badge"><img src="image2.jpg"></div>
<?php }?>
```

Second (messed) statement:

```
<?php if (is_null($ContentPicture1Title) && ($ContentPicture1URL)){ ?>
   <div class="letter-badge"><img src="image1.jpg"></div>
<?php } else { ?>
   <div class="letter-badge"><img src="image2.jpg"></div>
<?php }?>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: And what isn't working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I guess your second is missing the is_null(...). But your question is not very clear!

Comment: yes my server does not give me correct errors ! both fields are being checked for null value.. in other words empty.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `$ContentPicture1URL` is a `boolean` variable, you need to invoke a function that can be evaluated as a boolean and/or compare it to another variable/value.

e.g.

```
if(is_null($variable1) && is_null($variable2)) {
    //Do something
}
```

or

```
if(is_null($variable1) && $variable2 == 5) {
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: PHP will cast the variable as boolean and return a true or false from it. Not exactly sure what are the rules, but it does. No need to be exactly a boolean

Comment: True, but the variable is evaluated as a `boolean` either way.  (e.g. `0 == false` and  `1 == true`). It's unlikely he would want this unless it was a numeric or `boolean` value.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php#112231) you need to use the second construct:

```
<?php if (is_null($ContentPicture1Title) && $ContentPicture1URL): ?>

   <div class="letter-badge"><img src="image1.jpg"></div>

<?php else: ?>

   <div class="letter-badge"><img src="image2.jpg"></div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This will run if $ContentPicture1URL is a boolean, otherwise you need to use compare operators ( `==`, `!=`, `&&`, `||`, etc.) or boolean functions (`is_null()`) in order to verify the condition properly.